# R code: What is the algorithm to calculate a gamma function in R as an iterative loop and with recursion?

Tags: algorithm, function

for the loop:
    gamma <- function(x){

```
y <- 1
for (i in 1:((x-1)){
y <-y*((1:x-1)[i])
}
return(y)
```

#for recursion:

```
factorial<-function(x) {
if (x <=1)
  return 1;
 else
  return ((x-1) * factorial(x-1));
   }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know you're doing something wrong?

Comment: I was not getting the correct values. I suppose to be comparing this algorithm with Rs built in gamma function.

Comment: You should include then the expected values, what you're getting, and what you've done to debug it.

Comment: well, im trying to get (n-1)!. the same answer I would get if I used gamma() function in R.                                                                                       for the loop im getting                                                         

numeric(0)

Comment: Given that a factorial function is: factorial<-function(x) {
if (x <=1)
  return 1;
 else
  return ((x) * factorial(x-1));
   }                                                                                                                 How would I change the function into a Gamma?

Comment: I'm not sure you should be posting your homework on SO.  It might be considered cheating--I personally wouldn't risk it.  You might want to consider asking the TAs during their office hours instead.